# How do I make a Kivy app update values from other files?

Tags: python, oop, kivy

I'm trying to make a Kivy interface that updates constantly when values imported from other files are constantly changing.

Questions:

1. How do I make it so, when I change the value of the "fk" variable in
   test.py, that the Kivy app updates, without me having to restart the
   program?
2. What is the use of "AnchorLayout" in class Interface(AnchorLayout): ?
3. I've tried to Google this, and still not 100% sure. Why put self in def build():?
4. What is the use of self.update in the code?

Questions 2 and 3 are unrelated to my main questions, but if anyone can help, that would be great.

What I have tried and failed:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
import test123
 
Builder.load_file('main.kv')
Builder.load_file('robotinformation.kv')

class Interface(AnchorLayout):
    val = NumericProperty(0)

class InterfaceApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)
        return Interface()
    
    def update():
        val = test123.numval()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    InterfaceApp().run()
```

main.kv:

```
<Interface>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        StackLayout:
            orientation: 'tb-rl'
            RobotInformation:
                id: _robot_information
...
```

robotinformation.kv:

```
<RobotInformation@BoxLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Label:
            text: app.val
...
```

test123.py:

```
def numval():
    fk = 101
    return fk
```

Comment: Your `kv` refers to `app.val`, but you haven't defined a `val` variable in the `App` class. Perhaps you need to move `val = NumericProperty(0)` into the `App` class.

Comment: Good point, I will try that!